# The position of the mouse cursor in pascal

Tags: console-application, mouseevent, pascal

Which built-in function/procedure in pascal that allows to get the position of the mouse cursor in a console application ?

Comment: Standard Pascal does not define a method of reading the mouse cursor position (because its definition pre-dates the invention of the mouse).  Which Pascal compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using Virtual Pascal in PascalXE ide.

Comment: Would be better to invest your time and effort in FreePascal and Lazarus, imo.  At least you would be more likely to get useful answers.

Comment: Virtual Pascal still has a group with a few users on Facebook afaik. Single digit posts per year though

Answer (score 1):

Since VP has some basic Turbo Pascal compatibility, I'd expect a Wincrt or "Crt" unit with wherex,wherey functions to get the coordinates.

But beware, Crt changes the way the screen is updated, so this might have side effects you don't intend.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **Virtual Pascal** died in 2005. The recommendation to use **Free Pascal** instead is a good one.

That said, VP is compatible with the TP7/Delphi dialect, and you should be able to link the [Windows Console API functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function provided with the language. Your best bets are to search for a such library, or write your own custom function(s).